# Creating table from two different tables sql

Tags: sql

I want to ask how to merge two different tables into one table. In one table I have an id, a family name and I have 3 records, in the other table I have an id, a computer, a company with 5 records. I want the new table to have the columns of both tables and it should output 8 records.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your question. A database tag would also be of help.

Comment: I believe you are looking for UNION ALL

Comment: is the id from table1 FK for id in table2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `full join` with a false condition:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a full join
     b
     on 1=0
```

Comment: it won't give 8 records i guess

Comment: @RonakDhoot Not? With on 0=1 none of the records should match, so I would expect 8 records.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `union all`:

```
select id id1, family_name, null id2, null computer, null company from table1
union all 
select null, null, id, computer, company from table2
```

`union all` is supported by all databases that I know (while `full join` is not always implemented, eg MySQL).

The above query will return all records for both tables, with a structure like:

```
--   from table1   -- | --      from table2        --
| id1  |  family_name | id2  |  computer  |  company |
```

---

Or if you want both `id`s in the same column:

```
select id, family_name, null computer, null company from table1
union all 
select id, null, computer, company from table2
```

Answer (score -1):

Table A

```
Id. Name family price
1.   A.        A.         12
2.   B.        B            13
3.   C.        C.            14
4.   D.        D.            15
5.   E.        E.             16
```

Table b

```
Id.  Computer. Company
1.     Lenovo.      Lenovo
2.      Asus           asus
3.       Acer.           Acer
```

Table c

```
Id name family price computer company
1.   A.       A.        12.     Null.         Null
2     B.      B.          13.     Null.        Null
.............
6.     Null.  Nulll.  Nulll.    Lenovo.   Lenovo
7.     Null.  Null.   Null.      Asus.      Asus
8.     Null.  Null.   Nulll.      Acer.      Acer
```