# Create a single time series master table using different tables from many different dates (SQL Server/SSMS18)

Tags: sql-server, time-series, append

I tried to find answers by searching articles on the web and SO suggestions (e.g., INSERT, ALTER TABLE, MERGE, COALESCE, INSERT INTO SELECT). This suggestion using FULL JOIN or UNION ALL is close to what is needed, but the new fields added to the table need to be appended to their corresponding "id" and not become new records as shown (Table C):  [Creating table from two different tables sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896782/creating-table-from-two-different-tables-sql)

SSMS2018 will be used to create a time series using data from different tables. Each date has multiple tables with different fields.  The field "id" is present in all tables (FYI: "id" is the company's id number).

Steps:

1. needs to combine all the fields into one new table for a given date.
2. a master table needs to be created with the data for all dates and all fields (note: there may be new "id"'s added or existing "id"'s dropped across dates). The goal is to be able to analyze the values for each field across all dates grouped by "id" (see example below).

Questions:

1. What SQL statement(s) in SSMS '18 are used to perform the steps above?
2. Is it possible and more efficient to use JOINs or another SQL function to perform Step 2?

Example:

Step 1:  Append the fields in Table 2 to Table 1

Table 1

```
date        id  field1  field2          Table 2 date    id  field5  field6
20191231    a1    4      4                     20191231 a1    9         5
20191231    b5    4     10                     20191231 b5    8         8
20191231    c9    2     9                      20191231 c9    9        10
```

Table 1 (revised)

```
date        id  field1  field2  field5  field6                  
20191231    a1    4        4       9       5                    
20191231    b5    4       10       8       8                    
20191231    c9    2        9       9      10
```

Step 2:  Combine / Merge Table 1 (revised) with Table 4 (Table 4 was previously created using Step 1) to create a time series in "New Table"

Table 4

```
date        id  field1  field2  field5  field6                  
20190930    a1    1       7        0      7                 
20190930    b5    3       2        6      1                 
20190930    c9    5      10        4      6                 
20190930    d11   0       5        3      7
```

New Table

```
date        id  field1  field2  field5  field6                  
20190930    a1     1      7        0      7                 
20191231    a1     4      4        9      5                 
20190930    b5     3      2        6      1                 
20191231    b5     4     10        8      8                 
20190930    c9     5     10        4      6                 
20191231    c9     2      9        9     10                 
20190930    d11    0      5        3      7                 
20191231    d11  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: This smells a lot like home work / assignment. **We are not doing your homework for you.** Please show us your attempt and ask where you encounter problem or needs clarification

Comment: FYI SSMS is probably not relevant to the question. SSMS is just a client interface to SQL Server, but its not the database engine. Of more interest is `select @@version`.

Comment: Where does the bottom row of the "New Table" id='d11' come from?  It's not in t1, t2, or t4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "appending fields" from Table2 to Table1, etc. and then creating a main table, the relational way would be to convert variable lists of columns into variable rows with a fixed number of columns.  This means 'unpivoting' each table directly into a normalized Test_Main table.  The 'New Table' output could be produced by a query using conditional aggregation.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST1;
go
select * INTO #tTEST1 from (values 
('20191231', 'a1', 4, 4),
('20191231', 'b5', 4, 10),
('20191231', 'c9', 2, 9)) V(mdate, id, field1, field2);

drop table if exists #tTEST2;
go
select * INTO #tTEST2 from (values 
('20191231', 'a1', 9, 5),
('20191231', 'b5', 8, 8),
('20191231', 'c9', 9, 10)) V(mdate, id, field5, field6);

drop table if exists #tTEST4;
go
select * INTO #tTEST4 from (values 
('20191230', 'a1', 1, 7, 0, 7),
('20191230', 'b5', 3, 2, 6, 1),
('20191230', 'c9', 5, 10, 4, 6),
('20191230', 'd11', 0, 5, 3, 7)) V(mdate, id, field1, field2, field5, field6);
```

DDL of main table

```
drop table if exists #tTEST_Main;
go
create table #tTEST_Main(
  id              varchar(10) not null,
  mdate           date not null,
  field_name      varchar(100) not null,
  series_val      int not null,    
  constraint
    unq_tm_id_m_fn unique(id, mdate, field_name));
```

Unpivoting queries to populate Test_Main table

```
insert #tTEST_Main(id, mdate, field_name, series_val)
select v.*
from #tTEST1 t1
     cross apply
     (values (id, mdate, 'field1', field1),
             (id, mdate, 'field2', field2)) v(id, mdate, field_name, series_val);

insert #tTEST_Main(id, mdate, field_name, series_val)
select v.*
from #tTEST2 t2
     cross apply
     (values (id, mdate, 'field5', field5),
             (id, mdate, 'field6', field6)) v(id, mdate, field_name, series_val);

insert #tTEST_Main(id, mdate, field_name, series_val)
select v.*
from #tTEST4 t4
     cross apply
     (values (id, mdate, 'field1', field1),
             (id, mdate, 'field2', field2),
             (id, mdate, 'field5', field5),
             (id, mdate, 'field6', field6)) v(id, mdate, field_name, series_val);
```

Query to output "New Table" results

```
select id, mdate, 
       max(case when field_name='field1' then series_val else 0 end) field1,
       max(case when field_name='field2' then series_val else 0 end) field2,
       max(case when field_name='field5' then series_val else 0 end) field5,
       max(case when field_name='field6' then series_val else 0 end) field6
from #tTEST_Main
group by id, mdate;
```

Output

```
id  mdate       field1  field2  field5  field6
a1  2019-12-30  1       7       0       7
a1  2019-12-31  4       4       9       5
b5  2019-12-30  3       2       6       1
b5  2019-12-31  4       10      8       8
c9  2019-12-30  5       10      4       6
c9  2019-12-31  2       9       9       10
d11 2019-12-30  0       5       3       7
```

Comment: Response to SteveC's question: I wasn't sure if every "Id" needs a record for all dates in the time series, even if the id didn't exist on that date.  id "d11" was included in the example to indicate that certain ids will be added or removed as the "master file" is built-up by adding more tables associated with additional dates. It will take me a while to test your suggestion since there are hundreds of columns in the tables to be combined (and due to my low SQL proficiency).  Many thanks and take care.

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm grateful for the help.